# How to send image in email body Android

Tags: android, email

I am working on an android application which sends email (texts and images) to gmail, yahoo and other mail services. The version i am using is android 2.2 and it is compatible with 2.2 and above. I want to send images in the mail compose body section. I have tried doing so but whenever I sent mail either the images won't come or a small box is displayed in the mail body. I have searched many websites but did not get enough help. Please help me out with this. I don't want to send the images as an attachment. I want to send both text and images in the mail compose body itself. Looking forward to a quick and positive response from you guyz as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would use if i don't want to send the images as attachments, is to upload the images to some location on a webserver, then put the images in the email body as image html controls with src pointing to the images urls on the web server.